# DEPRECATION WARNING: Passing null, a non-string value, to unquote()

Tags: sass, compass, susy

I am running Sass, Compass, and Susy. I upgraded to the latest versions:

```
bigdecimal (1.2.4)
chunky_png (1.3.3)
compass (1.0.3)
compass-core (1.0.3)
compass-import-once (1.0.5)
ffi (1.9.6 x86-mingw32)
io-console (0.4.2)
json (1.8.1)
minitest (4.7.5)
multi_json (1.10.1)
psych (2.0.5)
rake (10.1.0)
rb-fsevent (0.9.4)
rb-inotify (0.9.5)
rdoc (4.1.0)
sass (3.4.10)
susy (2.2.1)
test-unit (2.1.5.0)
```

The full deprecation warning is:

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: Passing null, a non-string value, to unquote()
will be an error in future versions of Sass.
```

I ran "compass compile --trace" but it did not add any extra information. Does anybody know how to go about finding where the problem is. From what I understand it could be Compass or Susy. Please advise.

Comment: search your code for "unquote()"?

Comment: @DLeh, as per your suggestion, I've search my Sass files for the "unquote" string but there is none. I believe that Compass and Susy use Sass gem functions and one of those functions is "unquote", thus, I need a stacktrace or something to find what functionality of Compass or Susy that I'm not supposed to use.

Comment: If the problem is not within your code, you should file a bug report with the maintainers of whichever library is the source of the warning.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the problem is with Compass. What follows is my investigation that makes me conclude this. I found where this warning is displayed by doing a search in the Sass installation (in my case "C:\Ruby21\lib\ruby\gems\2.1.0\gems\sass-3.4.10\lib\sass"). It is the "..\scripts\functions.rb":

```
    def unquote(string)
      unless string.is_a?(Sass::Script::Value::String)
        Sass::Util.sass_warn(<<MESSAGE)
DEPRECATION WARNING: Passing #{string.to_sass}, a non-string value, to unquote()
will be an error in future versions of Sass.
MESSAGE
        return string
      end

      return string if string.type == :identifier
      identifier(string.value)
    end
    declare :unquote, [:string]
```

I put a "puts caller" inside the "unless" to see who is calling this function without a parameter and here was the output:

```
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/script/tree/funcall.rb:140:in `_perform'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/script/tree/node.rb:50:in `perform'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:468:in `visit_variable'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `block in visit'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `visit'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:363:in `block (4 levels) in visit_mixin'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:363:in `map'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:363:in `block (3 levels) in visit_mixin'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:179:in `with_environment'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:363:in `block (2 levels) in visit_mixin'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:84:in `perform_arguments'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:358:in `block in visit_mixin'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/stack.rb:98:in `block in with_mixin'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/stack.rb:98:in `with_mixin'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:346:in `visit_mixin'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `block in visit'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `visit'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:299:in `block (2 levels) in visit_if'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:299:in `map'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:299:in `block in visit_if'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:179:in `with_environment'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:298:in `visit_if'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `block in visit'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `visit'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:363:in `block (4 levels) in visit_mixin'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:363:in `map'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:363:in `block (3 levels) in visit_mixin'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:179:in `with_environment'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:363:in `block (2 levels) in visit_mixin'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:84:in `perform_arguments'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:358:in `block in visit_mixin'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/stack.rb:98:in `block in with_mixin'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/stack.rb:98:in `with_mixin'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:346:in `visit_mixin'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `block in visit'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `visit'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:299:in `block (2 levels) in visit_if'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:299:in `map'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:299:in `block in visit_if'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:179:in `with_environment'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:298:in `visit_if'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `block in visit'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `visit'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:302:in `visit_if'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `block in visit'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `visit'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:302:in `visit_if'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `block in visit'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `visit'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:302:in `visit_if'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `block in visit'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `visit'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:302:in `visit_if'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `block in visit'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `visit'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:363:in `block (4 levels) in visit_mixin'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:363:in `map'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:363:in `block (3 levels) in visit_mixin'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:179:in `with_environment'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:363:in `block (2 levels) in visit_mixin'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:84:in `perform_arguments'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:358:in `block in visit_mixin'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/stack.rb:98:in `block in with_mixin'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/stack.rb:98:in `with_mixin'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:346:in `visit_mixin'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `block in visit'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `visit'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:240:in `block (3 levels) in visit_each'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:240:in `map'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:240:in `block (2 levels) in visit_each'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:232:in `map'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:232:in `block in visit_each'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:179:in `with_environment'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:231:in `visit_each'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `block in visit'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `visit'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:363:in `block (4 levels) in visit_mixin'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:363:in `map'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:363:in `block (3 levels) in visit_mixin'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:179:in `with_environment'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:363:in `block (2 levels) in visit_mixin'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:84:in `perform_arguments'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:358:in `block in visit_mixin'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/stack.rb:98:in `block in with_mixin'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/stack.rb:98:in `with_mixin'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:346:in `visit_mixin'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `block in visit'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `visit'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:363:in `block (4 levels) in visit_mixin'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:363:in `map'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:363:in `block (3 levels) in visit_mixin'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:179:in `with_environment'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:363:in `block (2 levels) in visit_mixin'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:84:in `perform_arguments'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:358:in `block in visit_mixin'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/stack.rb:98:in `block in with_mixin'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/stack.rb:98:in `with_mixin'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:346:in `visit_mixin'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `block in visit'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `visit'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:430:in `block (2 levels) in visit_rule'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:430:in `map'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:430:in `block in visit_rule'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:179:in `with_environment'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:428:in `visit_rule'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `block in visit'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `visit'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:325:in `block (2 levels) in visit_import'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:325:in `map'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:325:in `block in visit_import'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/stack.rb:88:in `block in with_import'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/stack.rb:88:in `with_import'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:322:in `visit_import'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `block in visit'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `block in with_base'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/stack.rb:115:in `with_frame'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/stack.rb:79:in `with_base'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:158:in `visit'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `block in visit_children'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `map'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:52:in `visit_children'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:167:in `block in visit_children'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:179:in `with_environment'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:166:in `visit_children'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `block in visit'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:186:in `visit_root'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/base.rb:36:in `visit'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:157:in `visit'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/visitors/perform.rb:8:in `visit'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:36:in `css_tree'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/tree/root_node.rb:20:in `render'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/engine.rb:268:in `render'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:492:in `update_stylesheet'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:215:in `block in update_stylesheets'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:209:in `each'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.10/lib/sass/plugin/compiler.rb:209:in `update_stylesheets'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/sass_compiler.rb:40:in `compile!'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/commands/update_project.rb:49:in `perform'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/commands/base.rb:18:in `execute'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/commands/project_base.rb:19:in `execute'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:43:in `perform!'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/lib/compass/exec/sub_command_ui.rb:15:in `run!'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/bin/compass:30:in `block in <top (required)>'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/bin/compass:44:in `call'
C:/Ruby21/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/gems/compass-1.0.3/bin/compass:44:in `<top (required)>'
C:/Ruby21/bin/compass:23:in `load'
C:/Ruby21/bin/compass:23:in `<main>'
DEPRECATION WARNING: Passing null, a non-string value, to unquote()
will be an error in future versions of Sass.
```

As you can see the on the bottom of this stacktrace Compass is doing things and it calls Sass. I'm going to file this problem with Compass.

FYI: I posted the bug to the Compass bug tracking https://github.com/Compass/compass/issues/1924.

Comment: Might want to show how one would add that "puts caller" in there, most Sass users don't know the first thing about Ruby.  Nice job debugging.

Comment: @cimmanon, actually I never wrote a line of Ruby in my life. I searched for "ruby stacktrace" on google.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in [this thread](https://github.com/ericam/susy/issues/425), it is indeed a Compass problem, related to its box-sizing mixin. You'll find possible solutions on that page. I'm copying them here:

Solution 1 (which I've tested, and the warning disappears):

Add you own custom mixin, which will override Compass mixin:

```
@mixin box-sizing($value) {
    -moz-box-sizing: $value;
         box-sizing: $value;
}
```

Solution 2:

```
@mixin box-sizing($box-model: $default-box-sizing) {
  @if type-of($box-model) == string {
    $box-model: unquote($box-model);
  }
  @include prefixed-properties(css3-boxsizing, $box-sizing-support-threshold, (box-sizing: $box-model));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can create a safe version of unquote, so it won't be called unless it is really a string:

```
@function safe-unquote($param) {
  @return if(type-of($param) == string, unquote($param), $param);
}
```